# How to design a database to make the search faster for an entity with many custom attribuate without to uptate my system

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql

I am doing an to-B app which I have to meet the different needs of many customers.For example,such as people,one client has two tags, age and position，the other has a tag habits,but I only has a system.
I have tried many methods to solve this question:

1. Horizontal plus multiple spare fields
2. EAV model (entity attributes Value)
3. Stored in json structure

Because I hope that the code is set by the user, I will not use method 1.
As for method 2,I tested a million-level data and the query speed is slow, who can give me a better way to solve this? Or directions can be optimized to make method 2 and method 3 better? which database is good for my question? MySQL, MongoDB or other?

My question is that in a to B project, because each customer's needs are different, multiple custom fields are required. So, how will the database structure be designed and how to make the search 
 better and faster?

Comment: I would go for Postgres with a JSON column.

Comment: Do your users/customers have separate databases? If yes, then we for example created an interface to add custom fields (variation of your #1) and possibility to search by those fields (indexes, UI and other required optimizations).

Comment: I am really trying to understand your question. If you're looking at having a table with multiple columns for various pieces of information which the user may input per entry, then you may need to set up a table for the user with definite columns and another table (much like a meta data) with as many options as possible, each having a foreign key pointing to the ID column of the parent user table for each user. The choice of database is subjective in my own understanding.

Comment: I'm sorry for my broken English.What your understand is what I want to I say.And I tried this method and the speed is slow.So I need to find a better way.